# WebAPI - how do I "overload" the GET method?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

So I am new to ASP.NET webAPI and I created a controller called: UsersController, which exposes the 4 CRUD methods.
If the user calls:

> GET/Users

- this will use the default Get method

  public IEnumerable Get()

if the user calls:

> GET /users/1234

- this in turn will call:

  public string Get(int id)

BUT...
what if I need something like:

> GET / Users/Males

- I want to return all male users
  and

> GET /Users/Tall

- I want to return all Tall users

how do I override/overload the GET method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RouteAttribute.

In your Api Controller:

```
public IEnumerable Get()
{
}

public string Get(int id)
{
}

[Route("/Users/Tall")]
public IEnumerable GetTall()
{
}
```

More info about: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2.

Comment: Where do I add this ? my ApiController doesnt have attributes

Comment: Use the attribute in your GetTall() method. See the updated answer.

Comment: I am getting the following error: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Get(Int32)' in 'RESTServices.Controllers.recordsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

Comment: It's an empty controller, whatever comes as default with ASP.NET webapi.

Comment: Probably you are calling the Get(int id) method without passing a integer value. The call should be like "http://localhost/records/123" where 123 is an id.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to have a GET method in my controller to do /records/Male

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113752/discussion-between-max-bundchen-and-pacman).

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

> Route Constraints
> Route constraints let you restrict how the parameters in the route template are matched. The general syntax is "{parameter:constraint}". For example:

```
[Route("users/{id:int}")]
public User GetUserById(int id) { ... }

Route("users/{name}")]
public User GetUserByName(string name) { ... }
```